# Two variants of a db_create_resources(…) function

Tags: c, comparative-review, database

After reading [noobs](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.ch/2008/02/portrait-of-n00b.html), I'm interested in possible way to improve readability of the following short snippet.

- a `struct pictdb_file` is a small file system containing a `metadata` array and a file descriptor `fpdb`.
- the function allocates the resources, and forwards initialization to `db_create_logic`.

How can I improve the readability of this snippet ? Please comment about: the syntax, white-lines, comments, function extracting, etc.

Also, which version do you prefer and why ?

version 1:

```
enum error_codes
db_create_resources(const char* db_filename, struct pictdb_file* db_file)
{
    //allocate metadata
    db_file->metadata = calloc(db_file->header.max_files, sizeof(pict_metadata));

    if (db_file->metadata == NULL) {
        return ERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
    }

    //open fpdb
    db_file->fpdb = fopen(db_filename, "wb");

    if (db_file->fpdb == NULL) {
        free(db_file->metadata);
        db_file->metadata = NULL;
        return ERR_IO;
    }

    //forward
    enum error_codes e;
    e = db_create_logic(db_filename, db_file);

    //release resources
    free(db_file->metadata);
    db_file->metadata = NULL;
    db_close(db_file);

    return e;
}
```

version 2: (comment and blank-lines changes)

```
enum error_codes
db_create_resources(const char* db_filename, struct pictdb_file* db_file)
{
    db_file->metadata = calloc(db_file->header.max_files, sizeof(pict_metadata));
    if (db_file->metadata == NULL) {
        return ERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
    }

    db_file->fpdb = fopen(db_filename, "wb");
    if (db_file->fpdb == NULL) {
        free(db_file->metadata);
        db_file->metadata = NULL;
        return ERR_IO;
    }

    enum error_codes e;
    e = db_create_logic(db_filename, db_file);

    free(db_file->metadata);
    db_file->metadata = NULL;
    db_close(db_file);

    return e;
}
```

Comment: Not much to review, but also not much to change.  It looks fine to me except I'd delete all of the comments.  They're mostly useless because they say the same thing that the code does.

Comment: @Edward, exactly the kind of comment I hoped for, thanks. [I edited with an alternative]

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: my mistake, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There's no specification. What does this function do? What arguments should I pass? What are the preconditions on `db_file`? (It looks as if I might have to fill in some of the fields, but which ones?)
2. "resources" is spelled thus.
3. The function does not check the preconditions.
4. Mixing `fopen` and `db_close` seems confusing and error-prone. `fopen` should be paired with `fclose`, and `db_close` should be paired with `db_open`.
5. If the call to `fopen` fails, it looks as if you lose information about the cause of the error. `fopen` can fail due to permissions (EACCES), lack of disk space (ENOSPC), missing directory (ENOENT), and so on, but these all get converted to `ERR_IO`.
6. The function uses `db_file->metadata` to hold a pointer to some memory, but this memory is not actually used by the function, and by the end of the function the memory is freed and the pointer set to NULL. It seems wrong to use the `db_file` structure this way. If `db_create_logic` needs some temporary memory, it should allocate it itself (and preferably in a local variable, not in the `db_file` structure).
7. The cleanup logic for `db_file->metadata` appears twice. This is a bad idea: if you changed it in one of the places, would you remember to change it in the other? Consider refactoring the error handling code to look like this:

   ```
   enum error_codes
   db_create_resources(const char* db_filename, struct pictdb_file* db_file)
   {
       enum error_codes e;

       db_file->metadata = calloc(db_file->header.max_files,
                                  sizeof *db_file->metadata);
       if (db_file->metadata == NULL) {
           e = ERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
           goto fail_calloc;
       }

       db_file->fpdb = fopen(db_filename, "wb");
       if (db_file->fpdb == NULL) {
           e = ERR_IO;
           goto fail_fopen;
       }

       e = db_create_logic(db_filename, db_file);
       db_close(db_file);
   fail_fopen:
       free(db_file->metadata);
       db_file->metadata = NULL;
   fail_calloc:
       return e;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and interesting ideas. I edited my question to be more explicit about args checking and db_close().

Comment: I rolled back your edit: it is confusing if the question no longer matches the answers. [See the FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

The version without comments looks fine to me.  What I would say is that unless you're working in a very constrained system, or have significant memory requirements this:

```
db_file->fpdb = fopen(db_filename, "wb");
```

is far more likely to fail than this:

```
db_file->metadata = calloc(db_file->header.max_files, sizeof(pict_metadata));
```

With that in mind, I'd be inclined to do the memory allocation and file opening the other way around, however that's largely a matter of taste.

Does the `db_close` function call `fclose` on `db_file->fpdb`, if so this feels wrong, since you're explicitly calling `fopen` in your `db_create_ressources` method, I would expect the close in the same place.

Comment: thanks for you answer and remarks. I added an example about db_close()... but you're right this is confusing. `db_close` frees the memory and closes the file handler. So I guess that I could just call it instead of `free()` ... or not and be explicit even though that's code duplication ?